# using @MockBean for a List

Tags: java, spring-boot-test

I have a Spring Boot test that uses `@WebMvcTest` . I need to update my controller under test, so that it now accepts a list of Item as a constructor parameter. That list of elements is parsed in the constructor to configure the controller as I expect.

I am used to use `@MockBean` to mock a dependency in that case... But since the constructor parameter is a List, it doesn't work if I apply the annotation on the list : I don't want to mock the List, I want to mock the Item elements in the list..

What's the approach here ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's actually very simple : just use `@MockBean` on a couple of Item, like

```
@MockBean
private Item  mockItem1;

@MockBean
private Item mockItem2;
```

These mocks will be instantiated, and injected as a list in the controller constructor

Comment: Did you test this? It does not work for me, due to "java.lang.IllegalStateException: Duplicate mock definition". I think you have to use a qualifier here like `  @MockBean(name = "name")`.

Comment: @UNIQUEorn I have tested with what you said and it works